# How to remove whitespace from outside of container

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI container component that I am wrapping my page in but there exists a whitespace on the outside that I cannot get rid of. I have tried adjust the `margin` and `padding` to `0` but it doesnt seem to have any effect. Anyone have any CSS workaround so that the component fills the entire width?[image]

Comment: which element you've set the padding and margin? Can you try setting its body? `body{ padding:0px; margin:0px; }`. Also, it is not recommended but you can try to use the `!important`. for example `#TheContainer{ padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; }`, if this works it means you have a problem with your selector.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Don't style a Container component. Just use div or Box.

Comment: I noticed this happens if one Grid item is e.g. `xs={'auto'}` and there is none with `xs={ true }`, while the rest of them take "too much" space (whatever "too much" is). The space seems to be the size of one of the Grid items, probably the last one. But it also happened to me under other circumstances.

Comment: I found some solutions to a more general problem, which might be the root cause of your problem as well: [white-space-below-mui-grid-container-which-is-not-a-padding-or-margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71499331/white-space-below-mui-grid-container-which-is-not-a-padding-or-margin)

Answer (score 1):

You can style default html elements so that they have 0 for padding and margin.

Using [globalStyles API](https://mui.com/api/global-styles/#main-content)

```
// src/GlobalStyles.js
import { GlobalStyles as MuiGlobalStyles } from '@mui/material';

const GlobalStyles = () => {
  return (
    <MuiGlobalStyles styles={{
      '*': {
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
      },
      html: {
        // add your custom styles
      },
      ...
    }} />
  );
};

export default GlobalStyles;

// src/App.js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <GlobalStyles />
    ...
  );
};

...
```