# "Magic" white space below nested flex box (which is not a padding or margin)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

<sub>(Note: Original title was *"White space below MUI Grid container (which is not a padding or margin)"*, but this is not related to MUI, but CSS in general)</sub>

How can I avoid the extra white space below nested <del>MUI Grid container</del> flex boxes with dynamic and fixed size items (in a clean way) ?

I am interested in the "correct" <del>MUI</del> way of doing this kind of layout.

Apparently the content is considered "not fitting into the available width", but if I reduce the width of any content or spacing, then the content doesn't fill the whole width anymore (of course).

The code:

```
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';

export default function App(){
    return <div>
        <Grid container direction={ 'column' }>
            <Grid item style={{ border: 'solid 1px #f00' }}>

                <Grid container style={{ border: 'solid 1px #0f0' }}>
                    <Grid item xs={ true /* or false or 'auto' or 7 */ }>
                        <div style={{ height: '100px', width: '1px', backgroundColor: '#399' }} />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={ 3 }>
                        <div style={{ height: '130px', width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#00f' }} />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

                {/* (here some mysterious space is displayed, if no other content follows) */ }

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </div>;
};
```

Apparently this happens e.g. if these conditions are met:

- nested MUI Grid containers
- (inner) MUI Grid item sizes include a specified size (a number 1-12) and a not specified size ('auto', true, false)
- there is none or only small conent following the inner MUI Grid container

Apparently the size of the extra space is exactly the space that would be needed to fit the last Grid item.

[image: screenshot / illustration]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### To summarize again:

The two boxes are `50%` and `auto`, so one box takes half of the screen, and the other takes the space needed for its content, e.g. `100px`;

Of course, if the window is **smaller** than 2 x `100px`, then the `50%`-box can not be `50%` anymore (because this `50%` needs to be at least `100px`, because of the other box).
Therefore one box gets placed below the other, instead of next to it.

This is all fine, and there should be no problem if the window is **larger** than 2 x `100px`. But this is where the **extra space** is added in this case of nested Grid containers.

#### Analysis:

Now I don't know how or in which order exactly the browser will determine or apply all the different sizes,
but I ***guess*** that the browser might do something like this:

1. Assume no specific window size, and apply some abstract "half size" for the `50%`-box and `0` for the `auto`-box.
2. Find the `100px` content, which doesn't fit into the `0` box, and place the `100px`-box below the `50%`-box.
3. Adjust the height of the parent container
4. Find that the window width is large enough to fit everything inside it, and place the boxes next to each other again.
5. Forget to adjust the height of the parent container again
   *(note that the browser also needs to be careful not to infinitely adjust the parent according to the child, and the child according to the parent)*

This will surely not be what the browser *actually* does, but it might be *something like it*.

So my basic idea was to tell the browser "as soon as possible" how much space will be needed
*(e.g. declare percentages instead of `auto` for outer elements, and let the `auto` sizing happen at the inner elements.)*,
and this lead me to some solutions, which should work in different situations:

#### Solutions

##### 1. Set the `width` of the outer item

```
<Grid container direction={ 'column' }>
    <Grid item style={{ width: '100%' }}>          <---- set width here 
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={ 6 }>{/* ... */}</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={ true }>{/* ... */}</Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

*Contra:*
This changes the behavior of an ancestor, which is never a good approach, because the ancestor might have other descendants (now or in the future) that require the previous behavior.

##### 2. Set `min-width` of the 50 % container

Set the `min-width: 100px` for the `50%`-box (i.e. calculate what `50%` should be at least).

*This way the browser knows in advance that `50%` + `100px` needs to be at least `200px`.*

```
...
<Grid item xs={ 6 } style={{ minWidth: '150px' }}>{/* ... */}</Grid>
<Grid item xs={ true }>{/* ... */}</Grid>
...
```

*Contra:*

- The 50 % container can not shrink smaller anymore if the window size gets smaller than `200px`
- If the `150px` value or the percentage needs to be changed, it has to be changed in two places (unwanted relation / coupling)

##### 3. Set `nowrap` for the outer Grid container

Set `flex-wrap: nowrap` for the outer Grid container.

*This way the browser will overflow the items instead of placing them below each other, no extra height is added in an intermediate step,
and no height needs to be corrected after the width is corrected.*

```
<Grid container direction={ 'column' } style={{ flexWrap: 'nowrap' }}>
    <Grid item>
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={ 6 }>{/* ... */}</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={ true }>{/* ... */}</Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

*Contra:*

- This changes the behavior of an ancestor (same problem as solution #1)
- We declare *"don't wrap around if the window gets too small"*, but that's not what we want. We just want *"fit everything inside the container, IF the window is large enough"*.

##### 4. `max-width` instead of `width`

Set the `max-width` instead of the `width` of the `100px`-box.

*This way the browser never has a problem to fit the `150px`-box next to the `50%`-box, because it is allowed to shrink.*

*Contra:*
The `100px`-box will shrink below `100px` if the screen gets too small, which might not be the desired behavior.

##### 5. Another Grid container inside the `auto` Grid item

Instead of having 2 boxes with relative and absolute values mixed (`50%` and `100px`), use 2 boxes with `50%` each,
and add another container inside the second `50%` container, with the relatively sized item inside it.

E.g.:

```
<Grid container direction={ 'column' }>     // outer container
    <Grid item>
        <Grid container>                    // inner container

            <Grid item xs={ 6 }>               // left 50 % box 
            </Grid>

            <Grid container item xs={ 6 }>     // right 50 % box <--- another container
            
                <Grid item xs={ true }>           // (optional space or other content)
                </Grid>
                
                <Grid item xs={ 'auto' }>         // fixed pixel width 
                    <div style={{ height: '50px', width: '150px' }} />
                </Grid>
                
            </Grid>            
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case use overflow: hidden;
It worked for me[image]

when I used overflow: hidden; both the columns became equal.[image]